# Ktor static content does not work properly

Tags: kotlin, backend, ktor

I am writing an app with a post function.

The post contents will be stored in these paths:

```
const val PROFILE_PICTURE_PATH = "build/resources/main/static/profile_pictures/"
const val BANNER_IMAGE_PATH = "build/resources/main/static/banner_images/"
const val POST_CONTENT_PATH = "build/resources/main/static/post_contents/"
```

And Route.kt file with this

```
static {
    resources("static")
}
```

When I run the server in localhost, I can get the content. However, when I deploy the backend to the server, I can not get images.

Comment: Are those files stored statically and bundled in a JAR, or are they posted to the server?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman All the files will be posted to the server while creating a post.

Comment: The problem is that resources are packed into a JAR file, and Ktor serves them from a classpath. If files are posted and saved to a local filesystem, they aren't necessarily available on the classpath.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman so under this situation, what specific path can i use?

Comment: You can store files in a local filesystem and serve them via the `files` method instead of `resources` https://ktor.io/docs/serving-static-content.html#serve-all-files.